# How System Call Works

Tags: linux

I was studying system calls from my operating systems course until this image appeared and I couldn't exactly understand its content.
Can anyone explain to me what is going on in user space and kernel space?

[image: System Call]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to Explain the mechanism of a system call to answer to your question:

- When a System call is invoked a **software interrupt** is raised in *user space* ( or better in ***user mode*** ).
- At this point, *ever in user mode*, **the state of the user program is saved into memory**.
- After that there is the **transaction in the kernel mode** ( or *kernel space* ) **to handle the interrupt, and return the value to the user space**.
- Then ,*in user mode*, **the state of the running user program is restored from memory and the execution goes ahead**.

I leave you a complete description of system call in this link : [Kernel System Call](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/ksys/)